# REDIS: Jedis Client as Plug-in Dependencies OSGi Bundle

Tags: java, plugins, redis, osgi-bundle, jedis

I have to use a jedis client in my Plug-in Project and run all on an OSGi Container (e.g. Equinox on Eclipse).
I found this: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jedis

I put it in plugins folder in eclipse, but I can't find it in "Imported Packages" in MANIFEST.MF file and I can't find it in the Target Platform when I set the Run Configuration.

Seems that it is not a bundle. Any suggestion?